# Why is the class of '@foo Cons rather than PersistentList when inside a def?

Tags: clojure

A quick experiment under Clojure repl:

```lisp
> (class '@foo)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

This is more or less expected, so let's wrap the same expression in a `def`:

```lisp
> (def x '@foo)
```

```lisp
> (class x)
clojure.lang.Cons
```

I tried playing with `def` and various other forms but `'@foo` seems to be the only one that triggers this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in a fresh REPL and reproduced the behavior.

There is a convoluted explanation for the specific behavior you are seeing.  You have uncovered a peculiar corner in the Clojure reader.

The `@` character is a "reader macro" that is shorthand for the following:

```
@xxx  =>  (deref xxx)
```

The `'` character is another reader macro that is also shorthand for:

```
'yyy  => (quote yyy)
```

Put them together and you get

```
'@zzz  =>  (quote (deref zzz))
```

So the `quote` special form comes first.  It says, "treat everything enclosed here as a data structure, not as executable code".

The data structure `(deref zzz)` is a list containing 2 symbols, `deref` and `zzz`.

---

With regards to the difference in the `class` between a literal and a Var, we see:

```
user=> (def bbb '@foo)
#'user/bbb
user=> (class bbb)
clojure.lang.Cons

user=> (def ccc (quote (deref foo)))
#'user/ccc
user=> (class ccc)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Using "object oriented" lingo, a `Cons`, `PersistentList`, `PersistentVector`, and `LazySeq` are all "subclasses" of the generic "Seq" type in Clojure. They can all be used interchangably, and the unexpected difference in the 2 classes above is an unimportant implementation detail.

Comment: While it is an unspecified implementation detail, I'm quite curious how it happens to be different. I would have thought that `'x` and `(quote x)` would be identical in all cases. Did you happen to discover what quirk of implementation makes it behave this way? (Aside: a vector is not a seq. It would be incorrect for this to evaluate to a vector)